# Why does json.Unmarshal return a map instead of the expected struct?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

See this playground: http://play.golang.org/p/dWku6SPqj5

Basically, the library I'm working on receives an `interface{}` as a parameter and then needs to `json.Unmarshal` that from a byte array. Under the covers, the `interface{}` parameter is a struct that matches the json structure of the byte array but the library doesn't have a reference to that struct (but it does have a reference to the corresponding reflect.Type through).

Why can't the json package detect the underlying type? For some reason it's giving back a simple map instead of the actual struct.

Here's the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"
import "reflect"

func main() {
    good()
    bad()
}

func good() {
    var ping Ping = Ping{}
    deserialize([]byte(`{"id":42}`), &ping)
    fmt.Println("DONE:", ping.ID)
}

func bad() {
    var ping interface{} = Ping{}
    deserialize([]byte(`{"id":42}`), &ping)
    fmt.Println("DONE:", ping) // It's a simple map now, not a Ping. Why?
}

func deserialize(stuff []byte, thing interface{}) {
    value := reflect.ValueOf(thing)
    fmt.Printf("%+v | %v\n", value, value.Kind())

    err := json.Unmarshal(stuff, thing)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

type Ping struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've passed to `json` a pointer to an abstract interface. You should simply pass a pointer to `Ping` *as* an abstract interface:

```
func bad() {
    var ping interface{} = &Ping{} // <<<< this
    deserialize([]byte(`{"id":42}`), ping) // << and this
    fmt.Println("DONE:", ping) // It's a simple map now, not a Ping. Why?
}
```

But if as you said you don't have a pointer to cast ton an `interface{}`, you can use reflect to create a new pointer, deserialize into it, and copy the value back:

```
func bad() {
    var ping interface{} = Ping{}
    nptr := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(ping))
    deserialize([]byte(`{"id":42}`), nptr.Interface())
    ping = nptr.Interface()
    fmt.Println("DONE:", ping) // It's a simple map now, not a Ping. Why?
}
```

Comment: That would work, but I can't do that. The library has no knowledge of the underlying types used by the larger application. The 'ping' is received as an `interface{}` and that's that. Any ideas?

Comment: You can perhaps use `reflect` to tell the underlying type of the `interface{}` and create a new `interface{}` representing a pointer to it.

Comment: I'd love to see that--care to modify the playground example and post your modifications?

Comment: well, if you don't mind creating a new instance of ping (I'm not sure what's the assumptions here), it's pretty simple. But I have a hunch it won't cut it: http://play.golang.org/p/KAnA-uCb6b

Comment: I would suggest using `reflect` as well. It basically allows you to deal with generic data types without generics. I'd even say `reflect` is the answer to this question.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer - that playground might just do the job becuase the library may actually have access to the reflect.TypeOf(Ping) so it would be trivial for us to call reflect.New(...). Thanks! I'll edit my question to convey that the library doesn't have a reference to the struct itself but it may have a reflect.Type. If you'll edit your answer to include the reflect.New stuff I'll accept it.